# How do I get this skin-like texture in cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials

I would like to make a skin like texture that's like this. How do I do it?

[image]

Comment: It looks like something you could get with a noise texture and subsurface.

Comment: Hi :). What have you tried so far and where *exactly* are you stuck? This site isn't meant for full tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

As TheLabCat says, plug a *Noise Texture* into a *ColorRamp* with the 2 tints of skin color, plug it into the *Subsurface Color* input of the *Principled BSDF*, set the *Subsurface* to 1, increase the *Roughness* value, decrease the *Specular*:

[image]